# How to use LIKE and OR in the same query

Tags: mysql

I would like to pull out 3 types of data registred in one day.
I want to extract every row where toll, park or expence has been recorded.

I can get this to work:

```
$sqlq = "Select * from mydata WHERE logdate LIKE '$myDato' AND park<>'' ";
```

But how do i exted it to this:

```
$sqlq = "Select * from mydata WHERE logdate LIKE '$myDato' AND toll <>'' OR park <>'' OR expence <>'' ";
```

Comment: Do you mean `LIKE '$myDato' AND (toll <>'' OR park <>'' OR expence <>'')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `AND` operator takes precedence over the `OR` operator. In your case you want the presence of multiple `OR` clauses to do this you need parentheses to change the evaluation rules based on the precedence of the logical operators

So you should use `(` and `)`:

```
$sqlq = "Select * 
    from mydata 
    WHERE logdate LIKE '$myDato' AND ( toll <>'' OR park <>'' OR expence <>'') ";
```